# Shouldn't TSRANGE be timezone aware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 7.0.8, shouldn't `tsrange` be adjusted to the timezone when accessing it?

I have the `rule` model with the `validity` attribute. In the DB, the validity of the first record is stored as `["2023-09-24 23:40:38","2023-09-29 22:33:18"]`.

`Rule.first.validity` returns `[2023-09-24 23:40:38 UTC...2023-09-29 22:33:18 UTC]`

According to [Rails documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html):

> Active Record keeps all the datetime and time columns timezone aware.
> By default, these values are stored in the database as UTC and
> converted back to the current Time.zone when pulled from the database.

And `tsrange` is among the timezone-aware types

```
ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_types => [:datetime, :time, :tsrange, :timestamptz]
```

With

```
Time.zone.name  => "Europe/Zurich"
Time.zone.utc_offset => 3600
```

Shouldn't `Rule.first.validity` returns `[2023-09-25 01:40:38 +0200...2023-09-30 00:33:18 +0200]`?

Comment: Postgres has two time range types - [tsrange and tstzrange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html). The later has the same behavior as `time with timezone`. So I would say that it doesn't actually make sense that Rails treats tsrange as timezone aware.